# Getting continuous drag events for NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent, nstextview, appkit

I'm new to `NSTextView` and AppKit event handling in general, so maybe this is simple. I'm trying to get the proper way to handle *continuous* drag events on a selected range of text from `NSTextView`. That is:

1. User selects a range of text.
2. User clicks and starts dragging that text.

I want to get events when the the text is being dragged.

I've got a custom NSTextView subclass and I'm overriding `- dragSelectionWithEvent:offset:slideBack:` and returning `YES` but it's only getting called once per drag, not continuously.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: i have the same question.  did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple! Just override the mouse events of `NSResponder` (mouse down, mouse dragged, etc.) in your `NSTextView` subclass.

See where I solved it here https://github.com/Shopify/superdb/blob/develop/SuperDebug/Super%20Debug/SuperDraggableShellView.m#L129

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `draggingUpdated(_:)`, part of `NSDraggingDestination`, will do this.